# Is there a problem that has only a recursive solution?

Tags: algorithm, recursion

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is there a problem that has only a recursive solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094679/is-there-a-problem-that-has-only-a-recursive-solution-closed)
>   [Can every recursion be converted into iteration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931762/can-every-recursion-be-converted-into-iteration)
>   [“Necessary” Uses of Recursion in Imperative Languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011448/necessary-uses-of-recursion-in-imperative-languages)

Is there a problem that has only a recursive solution, that is, a problem that has a recursive solution, but an iterative solution has yet to be found, or better yet, has proven to be non-existing (obviously, this is not a tail-recursion)?

Comment: that depends what you call recursive. every recursive function can be translated to a non-recursive one by implementing a stack..

Comment: Yes; it is described in detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094679/

Comment: @Marc Gravell: That's absolutely great!

Comment: @Marc Gravell:Brilliant, we can find the same thing when looking at the index for Recursion in the K&R. (The index references a bunch of pages and the index page...)

Comment: Another dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011448/necessary-uses-of-recursion-in-imperative-languages

Comment: I think that's more of "do any problems exist where iteration is terribly bad compared to recursion" rather that "are there problems that absolutely require recursion"

Comment: I thin series like Fibonacci ones (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) are good candidates for algorithms that can be solved only recursively.

Comment: I think the question here is not if a recursive algorithm can be always translated in an iterative algorithm (and the answer is YES [1]). The question was: does it exist a class of problems which formulation can be expressed only with recursion? And also for this the answer is yes. For example to determine if a certain sequence of numbers is present in the infinite expansion of the Pi number [2]. [1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931762/can-every-recursion-be-converted-into-iteration [2] https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23547/does-pi-contain-1000-consecutive-zeroes-in-base-10

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Ackermann function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function) cannot be expressed without recursion

edit: As noted in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1095538/371122), this is incorrect.

Comment: +1. Nice. I think this is about the only real answer on here (well, besides Marc's comment).

Comment: Counter: "The Ackermann function can also be expressed nonrecursively using Conway chained arrow notation" (see wikipedia)

Comment: and "hyper operators" and "the indexed version of Knuth's up-arrow notation"

Comment: I thought it was just a shortcut to recursion but still recursion...

Comment: Interesting. The Ackermann function is not a primitive recursive function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function. According to this page, a language with basic arithemetic, comparison, and bounded for-loops can't express this type of function. But if you add in WHILE or GOTO you're Turing-complete again.

Comment: see my response at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094679/is-there-a-problem-that-has-only-a-recursive-solution/1095538#1095538

Comment: Weisstein, Eric W. "Primitive Recursive Function." From MathWorld--A Wolfram Web Resource. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimitiveRecursiveFunction.html

Comment: I think it's important to differentiate between problems whose "mathematical" definition involves a recursive form ... vs. whose computation can only be achieved recursively. You can compute the Ackermann function using non-recursive programming form - however you _will_ to store state for each iteration.

Comment: @LBushkin  I fully agree

Comment: So, would you say that "Any problem that can be solved recursively can also be solved iteratively" is false?

Answer (score 19):

replace function calls with pushing arguments onto a stack, and returns with popping off the stack, and you've eliminated recursion.

**Edit:**  in response to "using a stack does not decrease space costs"

If a recursive algorithm can run in constant space, it can be written in a tail-recursive manner. if it is written in tail-recursive format, then any decent compiler can collapse the stack. However, this means the "convert function calls to explicit stack-pushes" method also takes constant space as well. As an example, lets take factorial.

factorial:

```
def fact_rec(n):
    ' Textbook Factorial function '
    if n < 2:  return 1
    else:      return n * f(n-1)


def f(n, product=1):
    ' Tail-recursive factorial function '
    if n < 2: return product
    else:     return f(n-1, product*n)

def f(n):
    ' explicit stack -- otherwise same as tail-recursive function '
    stack, product = [n], 1
    while len(stack):
        n = stack.pop()
        if n < 2: pass 
        else:
            stack.append(n-1)
            product *= n
    return product
```

because the stack.pop() follows the stack.append() in the loop, the stack never has more than one item in it, and so it fulfills the constant-space requirement. if you imagine using a temp variable instead of a 1-length stack, it becomes your standard iterative-factorial algorithm.

of course, there are recursive functions that can't be written in tail-recursive format. You can still convert to iterative format with some kind of stack, but I'd be surprised if there were any guarantees on space-complexity.

Comment: That is not recursion elimination. When one replace recursive function with non-recursive one it is supposed to use limited memory instead of theoretically unlimited stack.

Comment: "Guaranteed to use a finite amount of memory" is not the definition of a nonrecursive function. It might be a desirable property, but it's not a definitional requirement. An iterative algorithm with a memory leak will use a potentially unlimited amount of memory, but nobody would argue that alone makes the algorithm recursive.

Comment: @jia3ep: this is recursion elimination. in fact, it already has a tangible benefit in some situations by moving the load from the operating system's call stack (which in many architectures has a limited space) into the heap, and avoiding the overhead of a function call.

Comment: This doesn't change the idea of the recursion in my opinion, you can as well implant a virtual machine in some non-stack way, and run your recursion code on top of it, I was thinking more in the spirit of a different algorithm. nice idea nonetheless.

Comment: @Jimmy, Hardware stack is much faster then using heap, so stack emulation has no obvious advantage.

Comment: I think the quetion here is not if a recursive algorithm can be always translated in an iterative algorithm (and the answer is YES [1]).

Answer (score 14):

In Response to the [Ackermann function answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094679/is-there-a-problem-that-has-only-a-recursive-solution/1094743#1094743), this is a pretty straightforward convert-the-call-stack-into-a-real-stack problem. This also shows one benefit of the iterative version.

on my platform (Python 3.1rc2/Vista32) the iterative version calculates ack(3,7) = 1021 fine, while the recursive version stackoverflows. NB: it didn't stackoverflow on python 2.6.2/Vista64 on a different machine, so it seems to be rather platform-dependant,

(Community wiki because this is really a comment to another answer [if only comments supported code formatting .... ])

```
def ack(m,n):
  s = [m]
  while len(s):
     m = s.pop()
     if m == 0:
        n += 1 
     elif n == 0:
        s.append(m-1)
        n = 1
     else:
        s.append(m-1)
        s.append(m)
        n -= 1
  return n
```

Comment: I assume the 'append' is really a 'push'?

Comment: well, this is a list in python heh.

Comment: How does it compare between the non-recursive impl and recursive impl compare? In other words, is there a performance or readability improvement to using recursion?

Answer (score 8):

You can define a [Turing Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine) without recursion (right?) So recursion isn't required for a language to be [Turing-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness).

Comment: in computational linguistics, the Turing Machine is above the Stack based automatas because it can emulate those (the strip can be used as a stack)

Answer (score 7):

**In programming**, recursion is really a special case of iteration - one where you use the call stack as a special means of storing state. You can rewrite any recursive method to be an iterative one. It may be more complicated or less elegant, but it's equivalent.

**In mathematics**, there are certain problems that require recursive techniques to arrive at an answer - some examples are finding roots ([Newton's Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method)), computing primes, graph optimization, etc. However, even here, there's just a question of how you differentiate between the terms "iteration" and "recursion".

EDIT: As others have pointed out, there exist many functions whose definition is recursive - ex. the [Ackermann function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function). However, this does not mean that they cannot be computed using iterative constructs - so long as you have a turing complete operation set and unlimited memory.

Answer (score 4):

All non np-complete problems can be solved with just sequence, decision, and iteration.  Recursion should not be required, though it usually greatly simplifies the problem.

Comment: So can the NP-complete ones. It just takes longer.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Undecidable problems are not NP-Complete (and they cannot be solved with iteration or recursion).

Answer (score 3):

It  comes down to how many lines of code is it going to take to solve the problem...

List all the files on your C:\ using recursion and then without.  Sure you can do it both ways - but one way is going to be a lot simpler to understand and debug.

Comment: Search in a tree can be Depth-first or Breadth-first. The former is naturally translated with recursion, but the later is more natural to implement with an iterative method.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Recursion is nothing more than a stack and you can achieve the same results by implementing a stack explicitly.

That may not be an especially satisfying answer, but you'd have to ask a much more specific question to get a better answer.  For example, theory dictates that in the levels of computing there is quite a difference in the range of problems that can be solved if you have a while loop vs. only having (traditional) for loops.

I put "traditional" in there because they really mean loops that iterate a certain number of times whereas C style for (...;...;...) loops are while loops in disguise.