# What problems can I solve using recursion?

Tags: php, algorithm, loops, recursion

Today I made one method with usage of recursion in php and get interested in it. what problems actually can recursion solve? For what things we can use recursion?

I started to search it on web and search and search, but I can't find anything.

So I am asking, what we can I do with usage of recursion?

Are there some limitations? Things that we can't do with recursion but with standard loops we can? I wonder if I could use now recursion normally in my code very often.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Take a look at this post for tips on how to write good questionsL https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: In most cases but not all you can use regular loops instead of recursion. Recursion allows smaller (neater?) code as compared to a loop solution. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094679/is-there-a-problem-that-has-only-a-recursive-solution & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660337/recursion-vs-loops

Comment: Basically any problem where a partial solution leads to the same problem with different input; e.g. coin change: I have some coins and need to pay €5.23; I use a €2 coin, and then I have a smaller collection of coins and I need to pay €3.23; or I start with a €1 coin and I still need to pay €4.23. Partitioning is another obvious candidate for recursion. Or generating permutations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every type of iterating through any data structure can be done with recursion. In fact you can replace every loop construct like `for`, `while`, `do while`, `foreach`, etc as simple recursion:

```php
function factorial($n) {
  $result = $n < 0 ? -1 : 1;
  for($i = abs($n), $i > 1; $i--) {
    $result *= $i; 
  }
  return $result;
}
```

Can be written:

```php
function factorial($n) {
  $forHelper = function($result, $i) {
    return $i === 1 ? $result : $forHelper($result * $i, $i - 1);
  }
  return $forHelper($n < 0 ? -1 : 1, abs($n)); 
}
```

This is called tail recursion. In some languages the two above produces very similar runtime code, but not PHP. It uses some memory for each call it does. For me both are equally readable, but I bet most programmers would find it easier with the loop, especially when it gets nested.

Some algorithms where you iterate a graph or tree will have a simpler version using recursion rather than iteration:

```php
function treeDepth($node) {
  if( $node === null ) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return 1 + max(treeDepth($node->left), treeDepth($node->right));
  }
}
```

An iterative solution here would need some way of keeping track of the places it needs to visit and thus you are doing some housekeeping that is handled automatically by the recursive version.

```php
function treeDepth($node) {
  $max = 0;
  $backtrack = [[0, $node]];
  while( count($backtrack) ) {
    list($depth, $node) = array_pop($backtrack); 
    while($node !== null) {
      array_push($backtrack, [++$depth, $node->right]);
      $node = $node->left; 
    }
    $max = max($max, $depth);
  }
  return $max; 
}
```

The limitation depends on the language. In PHP it allocates some memory for each call frame that is not allocated for a simple loop. The node traversal always uses memory since the process is inherently recursive.

Ultimately you should code in the way that makes your code as clear as possible without thinking about optimization. Use looping constructs where it is clearest and recursion where it is clearest. Only when you actually stumble on performance issues you should profile and rewrite the parts that use most time. I use to keep the original code as comment if it's short and documents what actually goes on in the more complex iterative version. In PHP function calls themselves are expensive.

Answer (score 4):

*What we can I do with usage of recursion?*

Solving recursive problems. The parent-child problem, where every child can be a parent itself again, is most the commonly one.

```
function doSomethingWithNode($node) 
{
    // Do something with $node

    // Loop over all childs, and run this code for those childs too, and for those childs, and for those childs, and ...
    foreach($node->getChilds() as $child) {
        doSomethingWithNode($child);
    }
}

doSomethingWithNode($rootNode);
```

*Are there some limitations?*

Yes. PHP (and other programming languages) keeps track of which code calls which function, so it knows where to continue after the function returns. This is called the `call stack`. Adding new entries to the `call stack` will take both some memory and some time. Mainly the first CAN lead to problems when you have a lot (millions) of iterations.

Depending on your installation the `call stack` may even be limited. By default it isn't. By installing the `xdebug`-extension it gives you a maximum of 100 nested calls (by default, can be changed in the config). In those setups it will lead to a Fatal error ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656089/solution-for-fatal-error-maximum-function-nesting-level-of-100-reached-abor)).

*Things that we can't do with recursion but with standard loops we can? I  wonder if I could use now recursion normally in my code very often*

Due to above limitations, recursion should be used with care. When you can solve it with a normal while or for-loop: use the normal loop. Most of the time it will lead to easier to read code.

When you care about portability (for example when writing an open source project), you probably want to have xdebug-users in mind.

Comment: PHP doesn't limit the call stack at all. A simple recursion that printed every milliont call I stopped after 55 since it started to get a little laggy and used up about 11GB memory, but it won't stop until it cannot allocate a new frame. You probably have xdebug installed and it adds a limitation that is configurable. AFAIK this beats many of the other Algol dialects when it comes to how often you can opt for a recursive solution.

Comment: I agree, in my script many times it went to max time of script execution, so there cannot be limit call stack

Comment: @Sylwester Apparantly I've  been developing for too long with the xdebug-extension enabled, and thought this was default PHP-behaviour. I've updated my answer to correct this issue. Note to self: change xdebug-settings first thing in the monday morning ;)

Comment: @JustynaBrosławska I've updated my answer, see above comment (can only add one @ in a comment...)